# EOF error trying to use user input as arguments

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with python and I'm trying to create a simple Ricky calculator.

```
def ricky_adds(x,y):
    num1 = x
    num2 = y
    if num1 >= 10:
        num1 = input("No. I said A number, not multiple numbers dummy. Try again :")
    if num1 < 0:
        num1 = input("Wow you're dumb, I said a number, not some imaginary shit. Try again :")
    num2 = y
    if num2 >= 10:
        num2 = input("No. I said A number, not multiple numbers dummy. Try again :")
    if num2 < 0:
        num2 = input("Wow you're dumb, I said a number, not some imaginary shit. Try again :")

    result = num1 + num2
    return result

ricky_adds(input("Gimmie a number. :"), input("Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :"))
```

But getting this error

```
Gimmie a number. :Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "..\Playground\", line 17, in <module> 
    ricky_adds(input("Gimmie a number. :"), input("Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :")) 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I can't figure out how to fix the error. Can I not use "input()" to get user input for arguments?

Comment: Are you entering a number or just pressing `Enter`? `EOFError` will pop up if `input()` doesn't receive anything.

Comment: Your code works fine (except for the fact that you're not doing anything with the value returned from `ricky_adds`).

Comment: Using your code here, and giving [5][Enter][3][Enter] as key inputs, i get no error

Comment: I get a TypeError error but not an EOF error in Python 3 and no error in Python 2.

Comment: What data are you entering for the inputs?

Comment: Additional information on my problem: I'm using the solo learn editor. I haven't quite figured out how to use text wrangler or idle yet.

Comment: I'm just trying to take 2 numbers and add them together. And if the numbers given are greater than 9 or a negative number I want the program to prompt the user for more input.

Comment: I plan to use the ricky_adds return in a print function.

Comment: This is either an issue with the information you're entering (e.g. you're pressing the ENTER key before writing a number), or your editor's shell environment isn't handling IO properly. If you run the code you've shown directly with the Python interpreter, it should work OK (or at least, you'll get another error from something other than the `input()` calls).

Comment: When the solo learn editor asks me for input it also says "split multiple inputs into separate lines". It does not look like you are doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you to everyone's help so far. This is what I have now:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Gimmie a number. :"))
    y = int(input("Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :"))

    print("Here's the answer. See, Julian? I out smarted your stupid books and did that arthritis in my head and got " + str(ricky_adds(x,y)))

def ricky_adds(x,y):
    num1 = x
    num2 = y
    lessthanzeroerror = "Wow you're dumb, I said a number, not some imaginary shit. Try again :"
    greaterthantenerror = "No. I said A number, not multiple numbers dummy. Try again :"
    if num1 >= 10:
        num1 = int(input(greaterthantenerror + ":"))
    elif num1 < 0:
        num1 = int(input(lessthanzeroerror + ":"))
    if num2 >= 10:
        num2 = int(input(greaterthantenerror + ":"))
    elif num2 < 0:
        num2 = int(input(lessthanzeroerror + ":"))

    result = num1 + num2
    return result

main()
```

---

Previous answer:
So I figured out how to use Textwrangler.

I also changed:

```
ricky_adds(input("Gimmie a number. :"), input("Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :"))
```

to:

```
print(ricky_adds(input("Gimmie a number. :"), input("Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :")))
```

and it worked. Thank you all for the guiding questions.

Answer (score 0):

YOU NEED TO RE THINK YOU LOGIC.. Numbers can be >= 10 and not be multiple numbers.
Consider using `nested if statements` for what you are trying to achieve.

```
def ricky_adds(x,y):
    num1 = x
    num2 = y

    if num1 >= 10:
        num1 = input("No. I said A number, not multiple numbers dummy. Try again :") # what happens after this statement? what is the purpse of this input. You need to nest the statements to continue in a logical manner.
    if num1 < 0:
        num1 = input("Wow you're dumb, I said a number, not some imaginary shit. Try again :")

    if num2 >= 10:
        num2 = input("No. I said A number, not multiple numbers dummy. Try again :")
    if num2 < 0:
        num2 = input("Wow you're dumb, I said a number, not some imaginary shit. Try again :")
```

Below is way to condense your code

```
if (num1>= 10 or num2 >= 10):
    print("you have enter a number greater then 10")
    data = input("try again")
    if......
elif (num1 < 0 or num2 < 0):
    print("you number is less than 0")

    return (num1 + num2)
```

Also, you want integer inputs, not what you have. Create a main function which can help you achieve that.

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Gimmie a number. :"))
    y = int(input("Smokes, let's go. Another number, c'mon. :"))

ricky_adds(x,y)
```

Comment: The string is supposed to emulate the way a character thinks and speaks. That character is Ricky from Trailer Park Boys.

Comment: The "multiple numbers" thing is supposed to be an indication of Ricky's perception of multiple digit numbers. And thank you for the suggestion to condense and nest, I'll try it out.

Comment: OK. Here's the code I have now. I still haven't quite figured out the best way to condense the if statements I have, but I cleaned up what was there, hopefully that will lead to an epiphany.